# Is it possible to have a release-sequence from a release store operation to a store in a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, memory-model, stdatomic

I'm aware that a synchronizes-with relationship will occur between a release store operation in thread 2 and a acquire load operation in thread 1 even if that load operation isn't directly reading the value stored by thread 2, provided that there is a "release sequence" between the release store operation and the store that is actually being read as long as:

1. The store that is actually being read is in the same thread as the release store operation.
2. In modification-order there is no store in other threads between the release store operation and the store that is actually being read (read-modify-write operations are allowed though).

However, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible to also have a synchronization when the store that is actually being read is in a different thread, provided that the release store operation is still happens-before the store that is actually being read. Is this explicitly not allowed by the standard? If so, then isn't it possible that the standard is incomplete because it makes sense and all existing hardware will have such synchronizations anyway?

Consider the following example where a, x and y are atomic int's initialized with 0.

Thread 1:

```
k = y.load(memory_order_acquire);
x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
```

Thread 2:

```
m = x.load(memory_order_relaxed);
y.store(2, memory_order_release);
a.store(2, memory_order_release);
```

Thread 3:

```
n = a.load(memory_order_acquire);
y.store(3, memory_order_relaxed);
```

where the question is, is it possible that we end up with k = 3, m = 1 and n = 2?

If there is no release-sequence between the store to y in thread 2 and the store to y in thread 3, then there is no synchronizes-with between release store to y in thread 2 and the acquire read of y in thread 1 and therefore it is not necessary that the load of x in thread 2 to happen before the store to x in thread 1, making the desired result of k, m and n possible.

But, if there *is* a release-sequence between the store to y in thread 2 and the store to y in thread 3 then there *is* a synchronizes-with between the release store to y in thread 2 and the acquire read of y in thread 1 and therefore the load of x in thread 2 needs to happen-before the store to x in thread 1, making the desired result of k, m and n impossible. Note that if the store/load of a wasn't there and we simply did the relaxed store of value 3 to y at the end of thread 2 then this would be the case (so it would never happen that k=3 and m=1).

In this case the store of value 3 to y happens in thread 3, but there is a release-acquire synchronization using the atomic variable a; hence, if n=2 then there is a happens-before relationship between the release store of value 2 to y and the relaxed store of value 3 to y. Doesn't that mean that there *is* a release-sequence and a result where k=3, m=1 and n=2 will never happen?

**Edit**

Note that running the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{
  atomic_int a = 0;
  atomic_int x = 0;
  atomic_int y = 0;

  {{{
    {
      y.load(memory_order_acquire).readsvalue(3);
      x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
  |||
    {
      x.load(memory_order_relaxed).readsvalue(1);
      y.store(2, memory_order_release);
      a.store(2, memory_order_release);
    }
  |||
    {
      a.load(memory_order_acquire).readsvalue(2);
      y.store(3, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
  }}}
}
```

on http://svr-pes20-cppmem.cl.cam.ac.uk/cppmem/
results in 1 consistent execution:

[image]

The reason being that there is no rs edge from node g to node j (and therefore no sw/hb edge from j to d).

To compare, when we put the relaxed write simply at the end of thread 2:

```
int main()
{
  atomic_int a = 0;
  atomic_int x = 0;
  atomic_int y = 0;

  {{{
    {
      y.load(memory_order_acquire).readsvalue(3);
      x.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
  |||
    {
      x.load(memory_order_relaxed).readsvalue(1);
      y.store(2, memory_order_release);
      y.store(3, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
  }}}
}
```

Then there is no consistent execution, i.e.:

[image]

breaks causality by having node f read from node e while f happens-before node e. The main difference here is that now there is a 'rs' edge from node g to h, which causes a synchronizes-with (sw) edge from node g to node d and therefore a happens-before (hb) edge between the same nodes.

Comment: My Q is more: why doesn't an acq gets to see the past of every rel **ever** posted on an atomic. I can't see how you don't that in practice. And why would any random thread doing a relaxed store destroy "history"? (Of course it's up to one thread to avoid destroying knowledge, preventing the others threads from determining which release was posted.) Linus dislike that C/C++ semantics because it's too abstract, high level and not in term of fences which is what the compiler does in practice.

Comment: There no reason at all for an acq to see any rel. The only guarantee you get is that IF an acq reads the value posted by a rel, then the thread of that acq will also see all writes to other memory locations that were sequenced before the rel. See it as if a thread "collects" writes in a bag without sending it to memory, but when you do a rel then the whole bag is written to memory before the rel is. While doing an acq does the same thing with asking memory to give the values in memory, so if you ask for the rel value (using an acq) you will get everything that was written before that, too.

Comment: "_that were sequenced before_" You meant that happened before, right? Otherwise it would be quite limited and useless. Assuming so... "_that IF an acq reads the value posted by a rel_" Why would it needs to see that particular value and not a demonstrably later value? I don't get the whole release-sequence stuff. That sequence should be all later stores in every thread.

Comment: @curiousguy The way I understand it, from the top of my head, is that there must exist a "release sequence" from the release to the acquire. You are correct in that it is possible that the actual value read by the acq is one that was written later in the release sequence, that is, a write done to the same memory location by the same thread (possibly relaxed) while other threads did NOT do writes (in modification-order) except RMW operations. Exactly as I say at the top my question here thus.

Comment: Aka, a RMW does not, but another write by another thread does, break the release-sequence, so there is no longer a guarantee that you will see all writes done before that rel. I'd have to look it up how happens-before fits into the picture... The only way I use a release sequence is to also get writes from the same thread (that are sequenced-before the rel).

Comment: "_so there is no longer a guarantee that_ ..." Can you imagine a compiler that would generate code that code that do not guarantee that **in practice**? On any existing CPU relaxed memory semantics or even plausible CPU. (W/o noticing by global analysis and using UB on purpose of course.) A CPU memory ordering unit doesn't even treat RMW and W differently AFAIK: both put the cache line in exclusive state for *some* time. Can you explain the difference at the low level?

Comment: Nope, I am certainly not a hardware expert.

Comment: In an exciting new development, C++20 removes writes from release sequences altogether, meaning that subsequent relaxed writes *on the same thread* as a previous write(rel) breaks synchronization with read(acq) observing the relaxed write. I'm not sure why they thought that adding new UB was desirable, but the paper is at https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0982r1.html.