# Is the concept of release-sequence useful in practice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-model, stdatomic

C++ atomic semantics only guarantee visibility (through happen-before relation) of memory operations performed by the last thread that did a release write (simple or read-modify-write) operation.

Consider

```
int x, y;
atomic<int> a;
```

Thread 1:

```
x = 1;
a.store(1,memory_order_release);
```

Thread 2:

```
y = 2;
if (a.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 1))
  a.store(2,memory_order_release);
```

Then the observation of `a == 2` implies visibility of thread 2 operations (`y == 2`) but not thread 1 (one cannot even read `x`).

As far as I know, real implementations of multithreading use concepts of fences (and sometimes release store) but not happen-before or release-sequence which are high level C++ concepts; I fail to see what real hardware details these concepts map to.

How can a real implementation not guarantee visibility of thread 1 memory operations when the value of 2 in `a` is globally visible?

In other words, is there any good in the release-sequence definition? Why wouldn't the release-sequence extend to every subsequent modification in the modification order?

Consider in particular silly-thread 3:

```
if (a.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 2))
  a.store(2,memory_order_relaxed);
```

Can silly-thread 3 ever suppress any visibility guarantee on any real hardware? In other words, if value 2 is globally visible, how would making it again globally visible break any ordering?

Is my mental model of real multiprocessing incorrect? Can a value of partially visible, on some CPU but note another one?

(Of course I assume a non crazy semantic for relaxed writes, as writes that go back in time make language semantics of C++ absolutely nonsensical, unlike safe languages like Java that always have bounded semantics. No real implementation can have crazy, non-causal relaxed semantic.)

Comment: @drescherjm Different languages with the same basic types, compatible data structure, the intent to be able to write non trivial code in the common subset and... and that's the focus here, exactly the same threading semantics except for the now deprecated/abandoned consume memory order in C++ which had carry dependency and kill dependency which apparently lacked in C (which made C's consume even more inane than C++'s consume).

Comment: @drescherjm C doesn't have class templates, obviously it has a different syntax. The term "C/C++ Memory Model" is used even in WG21 documents like ["Example POWER Implementation for C/C++ Memory Model" ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N2745](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/paper/N2745r.2008.12.16a.html). WG21 takes the common subset of both language and convergence of core language semantics quite seriously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a release-sequence from a release store operation to a store in a different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48292336/5376789)

Comment: @xskxzr None of the example is the identical. a) Thread 2 does release store not relaxed store. b) There is no H-B of `a.store(2,memory_order_relaxed)` in silly-thread, only causality. "_provided that the release store operation is still happens-before the store that is actually being read._" says @carlowood. I don't think H-B should be required in a reasonable relaxed semantic. **W/o causality relaxed atomics are meaningless semantic garbage** (think invalid values being read causing UB writing these values).

Comment: @drescherjm I removed the C tag. But I maintain that many issues are common for C and C++, even w/ slightly diff syntaxes.

Comment: You don't need to exclude atomic RMWs in the first paragraph.  An atomic RMW with `mo_release`, `acq_rel`, or `seq_cst` can also be the start of a release sequence.   Unless I'm misremembering the standard-ese, it's also a Release Operation.  (But however it's worded, it would be insane if it wasn't that way.)  Atomic RMW can also be a middle part of a non-trivial release *sequence*, but the "base case" of a release sequence is just one release store or release RMW.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't remember what I had in mind writing that. I will re-read the spec and change that intro.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first answer your question:

> Why wouldn't the release-sequence extend to every subsequent modification in the modification order?

Because if so, we would lose some potential optimization. For example, consider the thread:

```
x = 1;                            // #1
a.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);  // #2
```

Under current rules, the compiler is able to reorder #1 and #2. However, after the extension of release-sequence, the compiler is not allowed to reorder the two lines because another thread like your thread 2 may introduce a release sequence headed by #2 and tailed by a release operation, thus it is possible that some read-acquire operation in another thread would be synchronized with #2.

---

You give a specific example, and claim that all implementations would produce a specific outcome while the language rules do not guarantee this outcome. This is not a problem because the language rules are intended to handle all cases, not only your specific example. Of course the language rules may be improved so that it can guarantee the expected outcome for your specific example, but that is not a trivial work. At least, as we have argued above, simply extending the definition for release-sequence is not an accepted solution.

Comment: Of course *a thread that wants to publish a information would still need a release store (or fence)*; I'm not suggesting that you could communicate any information though non atomic objects w/o a release operation. What I propose is that once a release was done, nothing can undo it. One way to put it is that release-sequence is unbounded; but then the concept doesn't serve a discernible purpose, so I propose to throw away the concept and that **any acq pairs with all rel of the past**. (A lone acq would do nothing as previously.)

Comment: I agree with the general idea of this answer, but another thread doing a non-atomic store to `x` would be data-race UB if unsynchronized with the example producer.  With an `atomic` mo_relaxed store to `x`, this would work.

Comment: Also more fundamentally, a store is write-only.  The only way it "sees" the old value (or not) is that real CPUs use MESI so committing a store requires owning the line.  So yes real CPUs do a read-for-ownership as part of `a.store`, a lot like `a.exchange`.  But that's an implementation-detail / side-effect.  On a system with tiny 1-word cache lines and/or large but still lock-free `a`, you could imagine not reading first but just broadcasting an invalidate.  Or whatever hypothetical mechanism a non-MESI implementation might use.

Comment: Although the standard does require that a modification order for `a` exists (i.e. which all threads can agree on), so basically the standard does enshrine cache-coherence, and even calls this requirement "write-write coherence".  Any non-MESI system would have to ensure that writes ordered themselves wrt. other writes so this point is actually somewhat solid.